# Calling an Arg twice in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am building a simple application using Ramda.

I have run into a functional composition problem that I am not really sure how to address without creating what seems to be a needlessly absurd function.

The scenario:

I have an object being passed as a parameter. There are two attributes on this object, and some other stuff that isn't relevant to the problem other than that I'd like to not change it's state :

```
{locCode :<string>, LocationList : [<Location>], someOtherParams : ...  }
```

I have a single arg function which can convert a locCode to a location:
`fetchLocByCode`

My desired result here would be to take the `locCode` value, pass it to `fetchLocByCode`, append `LocationList` with the result, and return a new object with the new `LocationList` without touching anything else on the object.

Something analagous to:

```
(Param)=>{
Param.LocationList.push(fetchLocByCode(Param.locCode));
return Param;
}
```

What I've ended up writing to do this seems extremely ridiculous and leads me to believe I have done something horribly wrong:

```
const locListLens = R.lens(R.prop('LocationList'),R.assoc('LocationList'))
const appendLocList = (i)=>R.compose(R.over(locListLens),R.append,fetchLocByCode,R.prop('locCode'))(i)(i)
```

This solution 'works' but it seems as if I've missed some fundamental idea.

Would anyone care to present a more 'canonical' way to address this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with your initial version:

```
Param => {
  Param.LocationList.push(fetchLocByCode(Param.locCode));
  return Param;
}
```

I very much hope the mutation is not required. Let's remove it:

```
Param =>
  R.assoc('LocationList',
          R.append(fetchLocByCode(Param.locCode), Param.LocationList),
          Param)
```

We could use a lens to avoid accessing the `LocationList` property twice:

```
Param =>
  R.over(R.lensProp('LocationList'),
         R.append(fetchLocByCode(Param.locCode)),
         Param)
```

Could we get rid of `Param` entirely? Let's start by using [`R.converge`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#converge):

```
R.converge(R.over(R.lensProp('LocationList')),
           [Param => R.append(fetchLocByCode(Param.locCode)),
            R.identity])
```

Let's use [`R.compose`](http://ramdajs.com/0.22.1/docs/#compose) to remove `Param` from the first branching function:

```
R.converge(R.over(R.lensProp('LocationList')),
           [R.compose(R.append, fetchLocByCode, R.prop('locCode')),
            R.identity])
```

Any time you find yourself writing `R.converge(f, [g, R.identity])` you've discovered a use for the [`S`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#S) combinator!

```
S.S(R.flip(R.over(R.lensProp('LocationList'))),
    R.compose(R.append, fetchLocByCode, R.prop('locCode')))
```

Although this is neat, I think the `R.assoc` version is fine. Future readers would not enjoy having to make sense of `S.S(R.flip(R.over(R.lensProp`. ;)

Comment: Thanks! 
Your examples help this make a lot more sense - 
I was getting really lost trying to stay 'point free' and forgetting that it's still totally possible to just directly access a property.